# SQL (BigQuery) - Find unusual sequence of values throughout time

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a list of Ids with dollar values by day of week and hour of the day (this is from timestamp, so I just did dayOfWeek and hourOfDay for 1 of the weeks)

```
Id | dayOfWeek | hourOfDay | dollars 
1       1           1           0
1       1           2           0
1       1           3           0
1       1           4           0
1       1           5           6
1       1           6           5
1       1           7           7
1       1           8           18
1       1           9           13
1       1           10          19
1       1           11          18
1       1           12          13
1       1           13          19
1       1           14          10
1       1           15          16
1       1           16          15
1       1           17          17
1       1           18          18
1       1           19          13
1       1           20          0
1       1           21          0
1       1           22          0
1       1           23          0
1       2           1           0
1       2           2           0
1       2           3           0
1       2           4           0
1       2           5           16
1       2           6           15
1       2           7           27
1       2           8           11
1       2           9           13
1       2           10          11
1       2           11          18
1       2           12          14
1       2           13          14
1       2           14          10
1       2           15          16
1       2           16          15
1       2           17          17
1       2           18          18
1       2           19          13
1       2           20          10
1       2           21          22
1       2           22          0
1       2           23          0
```

I want to find the Ids where there are higher than average consecutive 0's toward the end of the day. I was thinking about using something like percent_rank() to find the "higher than average" cases, but I'm having trouble combining this with consecutive instances of the 0 cases per each Id.

Any help would be really appreciated, but please also let me know if I'm not thinking the right way, or if I should consider a different direction. Thanks very much.

Comment: what is `average consecutive 0's toward the end of the day`? Btw, would be great if you can edit your question to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: For example, there are usually 1-2 consecutive 0's (e.g. hour 22, 23 = 0) but I want to catch instances like the above (dayOfWeek=1) where there are 4 consecutive 0's (hours 20,21,22,23). Am I making sense?

Comment: formally - makes sense now. hope this also makes sense from business point of view :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH outages AS (
  SELECT 
    id, 
    MIN(dayOfWeek) AS dayOfWeek,
    MIN(hourOfDay) AS hourOfDay,
    COUNT(1) AS len
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      id, seq, 
      FIRST_VALUE(dayOfWeek) OVER(win) AS dayOfWeek,
      FIRST_VALUE(hourOfDay) OVER(win) AS hourOfDay
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        id, dayOfWeek, hourOfDay, dollars,
        COUNTIF(dollars <> 0) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dayOfWeek, hourOfDay) AS seq   
      FROM `yourTable`
    )
    WHERE dollars = 0
    WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY id, seq ORDER BY dayOfWeek, hourOfDay)
  )
  GROUP BY id, seq
),
averages AS (
  SELECT id, AVG(len) AS len
  FROM outages
  GROUP BY id
)
SELECT o.*
FROM outages AS o JOIN averages AS a 
ON o.id = a.id AND o.len > a.len
```

You can test / play with it using dummy data from your question as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([STRUCT<id INT64, dayOfWeek INT64, hourOfDay INT64, dollars INT64>(1, 1, 1, 0),(1, 1, 2, 0),(1, 1, 3, 0),(1, 1, 4, 0),(1, 1, 5, 6),(1, 1, 6, 5),(1, 1, 7, 7),(1, 1, 8, 18),(1, 1, 9, 13),(1, 1, 10, 19),(1, 1, 11, 18),(1, 1, 12, 13),(1, 1, 13, 19),(1, 1, 14, 10),(1, 1, 15, 16),(1, 1, 16, 15),(1, 1, 17, 17),(1, 1, 18, 18),(1, 1, 19, 13),(1, 1, 20, 0),(1, 1, 21, 0),(1, 1, 22, 0),(1, 1, 23, 0),(1, 2, 0, 0),(1, 2, 1, 0),(1, 2, 2, 0),(1, 2, 3, 0),(1, 2, 4, 0),(1, 2, 5, 16),(1, 2, 6, 15),(1, 2, 7, 27),(1, 2, 8, 11),(1, 2, 9, 13),(1, 2, 10, 11),(1, 2, 11, 18),(1, 2, 12, 14),(1, 2, 13, 14),(1, 2, 14, 10),(1, 2, 15, 16),(1, 2, 16, 15),(1, 2, 17, 17),(1, 2, 18, 18),(1, 2, 19, 13),(1, 2, 20, 10),(1, 2, 21, 22),(1, 2, 22, 0),(1, 2, 23, 0)]) 
),
outages AS (
  SELECT 
    id, 
    MIN(dayOfWeek) AS dayOfWeek,
    MIN(hourOfDay) AS hourOfDay,
    COUNT(1) AS len
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      id, seq, 
      FIRST_VALUE(dayOfWeek) OVER(win) AS dayOfWeek,
      FIRST_VALUE(hourOfDay) OVER(win) AS hourOfDay
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        id, dayOfWeek, hourOfDay, dollars,
        COUNTIF(dollars <> 0) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dayOfWeek, hourOfDay) AS seq 
      FROM `yourTable`
    )
    WHERE dollars = 0
    WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY id, seq ORDER BY dayOfWeek, hourOfDay)
  )
  GROUP BY id, seq
),
averages AS (
  SELECT id, AVG(len) AS len
  FROM outages
  GROUP BY id
)
SELECT o.*
FROM outages AS o JOIN averages AS a 
ON o.id = a.id AND o.len > a.len
```

As you can see here - `outages` sub-select calculates all zero-sequences with length of sequence and start of that sequence and outputs below

```sql
id  dayOfWeek   hourOfDay   len  
1   1           1           4    
1   1           20          9    
1   2           22          2
```

Final SELECT outputs only rows from outages where respective length is greater than average length (from `averages` sub-select) for that id

```sql
id  dayOfWeek   hourOfDay   len  
1   1           20          9
```

Comment: Maybe a ")" is missing after the `window` operation.  Just wondering, is there somewhere in BQ's documentation that discusses about this _window_ technique? First time I'm seeing it and really liked it. And great answer btw

Comment: thank  you @Will - consider voting it up if you like it :o) - i am checking ")" stuff and also will follow up with link for window'ing

Comment: @Will - your are right  - somehow i lost ")" when did formatting for the answer. THANK YOU! looking for link now ...

Comment: @Will - for `WINDOW` check [SQL Syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#sql-syntax) and [WINDOW Clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#window-clause)